# Expo Push Notifications with Baqend

Tags: expo, baqend

I'm wondering if anyone has experience implementing Baqend's push notification service https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/push/ on an Expo app?

he setup docs look like it requires modifying native code which makes me think it might not work with Expo... I really do not want to have to eject my app from expo.

Expo also has a push notification system: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications.html that avoids having to setup APNS and FCM, and it looks simple enough to execute a push through their server.  It's just a http post.

Would it make more sense to use Expo's system and save the device token generated by Expo in a field in Baqend's Device class?

Also if any of the Baqend guys come across this, the tutorial link for "Setup Push: APNS" on https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/push/ does not take you to a tutorial page.

Comment: Have you tried expo's first and then considered whether you need to detach to expokit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to modify any native code for using push notifications with Baqend.

Unfortunately, Baqend only supports APNS and FCM directly, but you can save the Expo token in the corresponding user object or a separate table and create a [Baqend Module](https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/baqend-code/#modules), which uses the [Expo Node module](https://github.com/expo/exponent-server-sdk-node) to send push notifications.

We updated the documentation today, and the links are now correct. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks Hannes!  The expo push system works nicely right out of the box, so I ended up just saving that token in Baqend.